# AsyncImageView getting crashed in iOS 8.1.2

Tags: iphone, ios8

AsyncImageView getting crashed in iOS 8.1.2, but working in earlier versions.

Comment: This question was asked with the purpose of sharing knowledge for others, that's why i asked and answered it myself.

Comment: There is option "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" i used that.

Answer (score 1):

Currently version 1.5.1 is latest that is to be replaced with your old version, it will work.